# Chan Park - Fundamentals of Engineering economics - 1st edition - Chapter 5 - Present value - 5.8

Tags: mathematical-economics, interest-rate, finance, accounting, discount-rate

hope I could ask some help around here. I'm working with Chan S Park book Fundamentals of Engineering Economics, 1st edition. I'm in the problem 5.8, page 171. Which states:

``Your firm is considering the purchase of an old office building with an estimated remainingservice life of 25 years.

The tenants have recently signed long-term leases, which leads you to believe that the current rental income of \$150,000 per year will remain constant for the first five years.

Then the rental income will increase by 10% for every five-year interval over the remaining asset life.

For example, the annual rental income would be \$ 165,000 for years six  through 10, \$181,500 for years 11 through 15. \$199,650 for years 16 through 20. and \$219,615 for years 21 through 25.

You estimate that operating expenses, including income taxes, will be \$45,000 for the first year and that they will increase by $3,000 each year thereafter.

You estimate that razing the building and selling the lot on which it stands will realize a net amount of $50.000 at the end of the 25-year period.

If you had the opportunity to invest your money elsewhere and thereby earn interest at the rate of 12% per annum.

What would be the maximum amount you would be willing to pay for the building and lot at the present time?´´

I saw it as a fun proposal since it integrates different kinds of payment series in one case and I decided to solve in two ways: On the one hand doing raw balance in a spreadhseet in order to comprehend how the balance flow irl and see first-hand the relation between balance and present worth. On the other hand, I tried to see al the patterns to make to explit hem and come up with the most concise formula posible, as if I was in the wild, alredy knew the most common factors and only had pen and apper to solve it.

After some days thinking about the formula, I ve think I found it and I attach it via this link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OlkdDvT1WxaMZbKnzQSZYskBwMPOF-Mv/view?usp=sharing

As you could see, I tried using the formula for geometric gradient with P/A factor, this edition of the book proves that formula in equation 2.18, here's the excerpt:

[image: Chan Park-Fundamnetals of Engineering Economics- 1st edition- equation 2.18]

Naturally, the present worth would be: Present-worth_revenues + Present-worth_salvatage - Present-worth_costs

I took inspiration from example 4-16 here: https://slideplayer.com/slide/10762322/ in order to check that all equally spaced values in 5 years could could be joined with and effective interest rate for that period.

The balance was done in the spreadsheet I attach here, that I made with open office Calc, I tried to evade using any odd formatting or formulas, but let me know if something comes up. You will also see in this spreadsheet the calculations for the raw formula resolution.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Pm5P6m-aEp4tEGY9o-doxoDku4oXiJVQ/view?usp=sharing

As you can see, there is a relative error between the two methods of 8,67% , which I understand is way too high to be a rounding error. Also, I understand that in a real life application 70 grand mistake would be inadmissible.

Maybe I made a mistake with the periods or maybe I have a conceptual error altogether, maybe another pair of eyes with a fresh head can help me point out the error, so I thabk you in advance if you could help me out. Hope you at least find it a fun teaser!